# Is there a way to connect to a Rails app's console on a linux server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have deployed a rails application using capistrano on a linux server and it is running without any problems. When I connect to my remote server via ssh, the folder structure of my app is quite different from what I have on my local machine. I would like to go to project root and say `rails console` so that I can have access to the console of my application. Is there a way to achieve this?
When I go to `~MyApp/` folder and run `rails console` it says command rails not found. I think that is probably because the app is running in another folder.

Comment: What happens when you do that?  You should be able to.

Comment: You can run rails through 'bin/rails' however the command not found makes me suspect the gem is not installed or on the servers paths.

Comment: `/bin/rails console` gave me `bash: /bin/rails: No such file or directory`. But my website is online. It is running. I must be missing a simple point but I don't know what...

Comment: did you install ruby on the server directly through the server's package manager or did you use something like RVM (or similar)?

Comment: I used rbenv I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bundle exec to the rescue inside of project folded:

```sh
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Comment: I got this. ` Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile` and I checked gem 'listen' is in development group already.

Comment: @moddayjob since capistrano deployed it to what is your `production` environment, it only has its production gems. Try adding `RAILS_ENV=production` before the command

Comment: Yes, this was the answer. @DanielSindrestean, together with your comment.

Comment: Updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed with rbenv it could be that you are defaulting to the wrong Ruby version. So you can run `rbenv exec` to get it to run on the right version, along with `bundle exec` to run the right version of Rails

So try running this:

```
rbenv exec bundle exec rails console
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up for anyone having the same problem in the future,
I went to `MyApp/releases/2020331231231231` which is the latest release of my app and there I used this command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console` and I was able to do whatever I wanted to do in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to move inside the folder where the code is.
Check Capistrano config if `deploy_to` is defined. (If it's not it should be set to `/var/www/#{application}/` by default [read here](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/))

Since Capistrano keep older versions of your app go to the current folder which is a symlink of the latest deployed version.

And run `ENVIRONMENT=production bundle exec rails c` or `ENVIRONMENT=production bin/rails c`. If doesn't work try with rbenv `ENVIRONMENT=production rbenv exec bundle exec rails c`